# How do I update my web.config for sending error through email in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, web-config

I am using Visual Studio 2013, the web server is running .NET 4, and I am getting a error on a web form on the live server, that works fine running on localhost.

It is currently emailing errors when I debug my web application through localhost and I would like it to send me errors when it is live (and if possible, on my localhost as well).  It used to send me errors from the production server but when I started debugging, it changed some settings and now it doesn't anymore.

I am assuming that the problem is a setting somewhere, can anyone give some general ideas on where to look for the problem?  Here is some code from my web.config for exception handling, is there some other code that could help clarify the problem?

```
<loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">

<listeners>
<add toAddress="cynthiat@myurl.com" fromAddress="sysadmin@myurl.com" subjectLineStarter="" subjectLineEnder="" smtpServer="###.###.###.###" smtpPort="##" formatter="Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f890890fsfds" traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f890890fsfds" name="Email TraceListener" />

<add source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter" log="Application" machineName="" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f890890fsfds5" traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f890890fsfds" name="Formatted EventLog TraceListener" />
</listeners>
<formatters>
  <add template="Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}&#xA;)}&#xA;Message: {message}&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;Timestamp: {timestamp}&#xA;&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xA;&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xA;&#xA;&#xA;Process Id: {processId}&#xA;&#xA;Process Name: {processName}&#xA;&#xA;Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}&#xA;&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}&#xA;&#xA;" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="Text Formatter" />
</formatters>

<categorySources>
  <add switchValue="All" name="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Formatted EventLog TraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </add>
</categorySources>
<specialSources>
  <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Email TraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </allEvents>
  <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
  <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Formatted EventLog TraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </errors>
</specialSources>
</loggingConfiguration>
<exceptionHandling>
<exceptionPolicies>
  <add name="Global Policy">
    <exceptionTypes>
      <add type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f890890fsfds" postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow" name="Exception">
        <exceptionHandlers>
          <add logCategory="General" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library Exception Handling" formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f890890fsfds" priority="0" useDefaultLogger="false" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f890890fsfds" name="Logging Handler" />
        </exceptionHandlers>
      </add>
    </exceptionTypes>
  </add>
</exceptionPolicies>
```

Comment: So does it not send emails from either now? What is the email address? I know google have introduced rules on passwords for gmail accounts and using them when sending email through an smtp client.

Comment: It sends emails when I'm debugging on my machine and it reaches an exception, but not when the page is live on the production server.  It's an internal address using our domain, not an external email address like google. I also want to add that emailing is working fine on both sides, I receive email updates on registrations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can't help too much with your specific question without seeing more of your config file(s) and/or error handling code that sends e-mail notifications. However, another solution to your problem may be an error hanndling/logging/notification framework, such as:

#### ELMAH

[ELMAH: Error Logging Modules and Handlers for ASP.NET (and MVC too!)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx)

NuGet package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/

Source - https://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Cloud logging - https://elmah.io

#### Enterprise Library

Microsoft [Enterprise Library](https://entlib.codeplex.com)

[Logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647183.aspx)  application block

[Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649552.aspx)  application block

Comment: Okay, I posted some code, hopefully it is pertinent.  At this time I'm not at liberty to add another framework, but I will definitely look into it for future use.